# Variable pointers

Tags: python, variables

I have a requirement as below:

**myConfigFile.py**

```
NAME1='Rahul Singh'
NAME2='R Singh Bajaj'
```

**myMainClass.py**

```
from myConfigFile.py import *

def printName(NAME):
    print('Name is : '+NAME)

for i in range(1,3):
    printName(Name+i)  **##the value passed is 'NAME1'**
```

**Current Output:**

```
Name is :Name1
Name is :Name2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Name is :Rahul Singh 
Name is :R Singh Bajaj
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: It's taking NAME1 as string rather than to take as variable.

Comment: While the answer of @madforstrength answers your question directly, yet I believe that likely a slightly different design of your programme would make the task for you much easier: use dicts or list and you might stop needing to compose the variable names - which is quite fragile. E.g. you could create a dict like `mydict = {'Rahul Sing': {'related property': 1, 'other_property': 2}, 'Singh Bajaj': {'related property': 2, 'anything else': "blödsinn"}}`. You then can reference the properties related to the names very easily with the name: `mydict.get('Rahul Singh').get('related property')`

Comment: And you would iterate over the single names just by iterating over the dict: `for (name,values) in mydict.items(): print("Name: {}".format(name))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
printName(Name+i)
```

with

```
printName(eval("NAME" + str(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, "NAME" is a string so you need to typecast int i into str(i).
Please find the full code below
**

**myMainClass.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from myConfigFile import *

def printName(NAME):
    print('Name is : '+NAME)
for i in range(1,3):
    printName(eval("NAME"+str(i))) ##the value passed is 'NAME1'
```